# Что означает *& в функции void someFunc(someType *& param) ?

Tags: c++

Что означает *& в функции void someFunc(someType *& param) ?

Comment: Необходимо разобраться чем отличается * от &. А потом сразу станет понятно что есть ** и *& и какие нюансы при использовании.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*& - это ссылка на указатель. Используется в С++ как альтернатива двойному указателю. К примеру, для инициализации указателя.

```
void someFunc(someType *& param) 
{
    someType * result = NULL;
    // Выполняем некоторые действия.
    param = result;
}
void someFunc(someType ** param) 
{
    someType * result = NULL;
    // Выполняем некоторые действия.
    *param = result;
}
```

Эти функции эквиваленты.